# plot.igraph params

Tags: r, igraph

does anyone know where is the proper documentation for the plot.igraph function?
there seems to be alot of parameters you can use but it isnt found in the manual, I'm using the latest version of igraph in R

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://answers.launchpad.net/igraph/+question/206380) you probably just did not find `?igraph.plotting`.